# Checking if something is a Bijection

Tags: combinatorics

[Reflection Principle's Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1wDD.jpg)

I was able to follow the proof until the end, and then the proof said to check that it was a bijection. How would one check if something was a bijection?

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you constructed a map $X\to Y$ you construct a map $Y\to X$, by just swapping $P$ and $P'$. Noting that every route from $P'$ to $Q$ meets $L$ anyway, since $L$ separates $P'$ and $Q$. So "routes from $P'$ to $Q$ meeting $L$" is the same as just "routes from $P'$ to $Q$".

These two maps are mutually inverse, so both are bijections.

Comment: Wait, P and P' are already reflections, so how does swapping them prove that they are bijections? And what do you mean by "maps?"

Answer (score 0):

Don't look too far! The fact is more or less obvious. A "formal proof" could go as follows:

For every path $\gamma\in X$ there is a well defined point $s(\gamma)\in L$ where $\gamma$ hits $L$ for the first time. Write $\gamma=\gamma'+\gamma''$, whereby $\gamma'$ refers to the part of $\gamma$ connecting $P$ with $s(\gamma)$, and $\gamma''$ to the part of $\gamma$ connecting $s(\gamma)$ with $Q$. Partition the full set $X$ into "classes"
$$X_S:=\{\gamma\in X\>|\>s(\gamma)=S\}\qquad(S\in L)\ ,$$
and in the same way the full set $Y$ into classes
$$Y_S:=\{\gamma\in Y\>|\>s(\gamma)=S\}\qquad(S\in L)\ .$$
For each lattice point $S\in L$ the construction described in your book defines a map $$f_S:\>X_S\to Y_S,\qquad \gamma'+\gamma''\mapsto \iota(\gamma')+\gamma''\ ,$$ whereby $\iota$ denotes the reflection in $L$. This map $f_S$ is injective: If $f(\gamma_1)=f(\gamma_2)$ then $\iota(\gamma_1')=\iota(\gamma_2')$, hence $\gamma_1'=\gamma_2'$, and $\gamma_1''=\gamma_2''$. Similarly one checks that $f_S$ is surjective. "Concatenating" these $f_S$ you obtain a bijection $f:\>X\to Y$.